# how to add username and password in android in http request

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, rest, httprequest

how to add username and password in http request to call web service? I have write REST web service and if user want to do request ,he neeed to request like this in terminal : 
curl -u username:password http://localhost:8080/user/folder

```
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("kyaw", "password"));
get.setHeader("Authorization","Basic a31hdzpwYXNzd29yZA==");
```

I used either way to do in android but get exception :

```
05-20 07:13:30.900: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(557): Shutting down VM
05-20 07:13:30.900: WARN/dalvikvm(557): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-20 07:13:30.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 07:13:30.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.put}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #18: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
05-20 07:13:30.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-20 07:13:30.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
```

How do i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is "You must supply a layout_width attribute" (copy pasted from your stack trace).

The error is unrelated to the code you are showing. You are missing a `layout_width=""` attribute in one of your components XML declaration.

Comment: I have set the attribute this is my xml file : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Result"
 android:id="@+id/textView1" 
 /> 
</LinearLayout>